# Sorting a complex records in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, data-manipulation, dml

I'm working on a personal project and I'm stuck in phase of cleaning a particular dataset. The dataset consists of records of an agent(having a unique AgentID) who visits different parking sites (having unique ParkingID). He is using an app to enter his records in the database. When agent enters into the parking site he presses the button for login and when he leaves he presses logout in the app (the agent can press the button multiple times, so there can be possibility of duplicate login and logout records). When the person visits a parking site, he/she can raise some tickets when he meets certain people at that place, thus marking `Tickets Finished` in the app.
The problem is data that comes into the database is only sorted to minute stage. Thus, the records having same time can appear differently in the database. One such dummy dataset is shown below.
[image: Unsorted Table]

I want to sort it together the event which finishes first should appear at top and the event that finishes later should come at the end. My desired output is shown below.
[image: Sorted Table]

I'm having no idea how to sort this in MySQL, if anyone of you can help me in figuring out how to solve this problem then it would be really helpful from your side.

Comment: You want to order by `Date` and then `Time` but how do you want to sort when two rows have the same date and time? Is it by `Event_Type` where _Log In_ should precede _Ticket Finished_ which should precede _Log Out_? What about columns `AgentID` and `ParkingID`? Should they also be included in the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Definite sorting needs each row to be unique. Your data contains complete duplicates - so definite sorting is not possible.

Comment: Does the values shown in `event_type` is complete possible values list for this column? Does the table which contains this complete list of possible values exists? if not - create it and add `priority` column into it (for example, `'Log In'` is shown before `'Ticket Finished'`, so the priority for the former value is higher then for the latter one).

Comment: @Abra AgentID and ParkingID columns need not be sorted in any specific manner. When date and time is same, for a particular parking site I want `Log In` to come first and then   `Ticket Finished` (if the agent meets specific people) and then `Log Out` row should come in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting by a `CASE WHEN` to break the tie.

```
SELECT *
FROM parking_agent_logs
ORDER BY `Date`, `Time`, ParkingID, AgentID
, CASE Event_Type 
  WHEN 'Log In' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Ticket Finished' THEN 2
  WHEN 'Log Out' THEN 3
  ELSE 9
  END
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=bcecba2709efb4bd80357c7219c1254b)*

Comment: This may mix the events for different `ParkingID` values which can be not safe for OP...

Comment: I doubt that one agent can be in 2 different parkings on the same minute. Unless he's a superhero.

Comment: *I doubt that one agent can be in 2 different parkings on the same minute* If AgentID is the most upper sorting criteria then it must be the most first in the sorting expression. And according the logic ParkingID must be second column in this expression.

Comment: It makes more sense that on the same minute the same parkingid's stick together, and then the agentid.  Like in the expected result.

Comment: @LukStorms consider a case where two parking sites are only separated by a boundary then both of them can have separate unique `ParkingID` in such case it is possible to be in both of the parking sites at the same time. The agent can login in one site and after logging out immediately, he/she can go immediately to the next site in the same minute. So, being a superhero is not the only possibility. :) :)

Comment: I see. Well, don't know much about the parking world. But I would try to ask the company of that app if they also store the seconds or an ID, and could include them in the data you receive. In most databases, a datetime or timestamp is more standard versus 'HH24:MM' time.

Comment: @Akina since Time column in the dataset is only precise upto minute level, the data that comes in database gets jumbled and becomes unsorted. If you notice my desired output carefully you will notice data for ParkingID 2108 comes at top because the agent logs out from ParkingID 2161 at 10:58 that signifies the agent must have entered 2108 first at 10:56 and then after logging out from there instantly at 10:56, he must have immediately logged in to 2161 at 10:56 and  later logged out from that parking site at 10:58. Thus that's my desired output.

Comment: @LukStorms you are absolutely right in many real world scenarios there is datetime column or timestamp column which is in the form of HH:MM:SS, and there is no denying the fact that if the time column was precise to seconds level then it would have been much easier to sort but here it is not the case. That is why I'm looking for help.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta You tell about definite data whereas **you must provide the most general rules set**. It should be a set of rules such that any people taking this set of rules and a set of source records will get **absolutely the same answers**.

Comment: @Akina, sorry to say but I did not get your point clearly. I'm explaining here, in my dataset the values in Date and AgentID column always remains same. Now, as time progresses the Agent can visit different sites and can log his information in the database. So, topmost preference for sorting will be time, then in case time gets tied as in my scenario discussed above, the parking site visited first should come before and then the site which which gets visited afterwards. In case we can't find it then simply group similar parking sites together in order login, ticket finished and then logout .

Comment: Did you notic my update btw?